# Updating modified source code's copyright

Tags: contributor, copyright, mit, source-code

A few years ago I started working on an open-source project, but things continued and now--years later--I currently maintain my own branch of the project. The project currently resides on GitHub.

The project has the boilerplate MIT license and copyright on every file in the project. I have simply been copy/pasting this into every new file, and have never changed it anywhere.

So my questions are:

1. How should I include myself in the copyright (and do I need to)?
2. Can I update all the current files' copyright to reflect modifications over the last X years?

Comment: I'm not sure how I missed that question, but thanks. I believe the first response answers my question about being concerned with updating all the copy/pasted copyrights.